# Localhost url of vue cli ends with a '/#/'. Why is that so?

Tags: url, vue.js, command-line-interface

I noticed that if I run a local vue cli server with the router function, the URL gets a /#/ at the end. When I enter another page (e.g. about) the '#' is between the 'localhost:8080' and the page name (e.g. localhost:8080/#/about). Why is this and is it possible to show the URL without it? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can visit HTML5 History Mode: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html

```js
    const router = new VueRouter({
          mode: 'history',
          routes: [...]
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for the link